# IBOutlet UIView in tableView cell repeating

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` for my custom `tableViewCell` that seems to be repeating as I scroll down.  The first 5 cells will have unique views, but the second set of 5 cells will repeat the UIViews from the first set of cells.  I feel like I'm pretty familiar with dequeuing my cells, but I can't seem to reset the `UIViews` before the cells are reused.  I've read plenty of SO answers about repetition when reusing tablebview cells but nothing seems to be working.  Could this have something to do with my UIView being an IBOutlet?

Each table view cell has a unique `UIBezierPath` that is set to the views path property.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* identifier = @"audioTableCell";

    OSAudioTableCell *cell = [self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[OSAudioTableCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: identifier];
    }

        Recording * recording = [self.managedDocument.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.waveView.path = nil;
        cell.waveView.minAmpl = [recording.minAmpl floatValue];
        NSData * pathData = recording.waveData;
        cell.waveView.path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:pathData];
        [cell setImageSize:cell.waveView.bounds.size];
}
```

I've already tried setting the UIView to nil in my `prepareForReuse` method in my custom tableview cell, but it made no difference.

Comment: What exactly is being repeated? The path in your waveView view?

Comment: Yes. The path of the top 5 cells repeat throughout the entire table view

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause that, unless pathData is repeated, or what you return from the unarchiver  is repeated.

Comment: Each cell is associated with an NURL (that is used to play the audio file) and the path data.  Both are fetched from the fetch results controller.  The NSURL's are unique since they play a different audio file every time.  I don't think the path is being stored/retrieved incorrectly, but its definitely being reused.

Comment: I did a test to compare the path data of two cells with UIViews that render the same path by doing `[oldData isEqualToData:recording.waveData]` and it looks like the pathData is different.  This leaves me to conclude that the UIView is being copied, without rendering the new path.

Comment: @rdelmar I found a hint.  In order to render the UIBezierPath for the view, `layOutSubviews` has to be called.  I noticed that it gets called for my first 5 cells automatically, but doesn't get recalled when I scroll down and the next 5 cells appear.  So pretty much `layOutSubviews` is not being called when cells are reused.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I called it manually by doing `[cell.waveView layoutSubviews];` and it does draw the new path, but it also draws the old path as well.  So I have two paths in my view...